# How to create executable RCP application using Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I have a working RCP application. Currently I do "Eclipse Product Export Wizard" for creating executable files from that application. I have already integrated Maven and Tycho in my application.
But I need to create the executable files automatically using Maven.

Can anyone please help regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Tycho maven plugin, its for eclipse packaging. you can follow this website http://modumind.com as a guide. A full fledged tutorial is provided by eclipse.org here https://www.eclipsecon.org/2013/node/1277.html

here is a sample eclipse application with tycho integrated, good place for you to start. http://www.modumind.com/downloads/rcp-example-20121112.zip